# How to create an array (javascript) from an php source

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am pretty knew to coding - so I hope my question doesn't seem too stupid. I am  trying to create an array for a dropdown-list.

Currently I am using this

```
$(function(){
     $('.test').editable({    
           type: 'select',
           value: "keine",
           source: [
               {value: 'DD', text: 'DD'},
               {value: 'HEAL', text: 'HEAL'},
               {value: 'TANK', text: 'TANK'},
               {value: 'keine', text: 'keine'}
           ]
      }); 
});
```

which works perfectly for creating a manual dropdown-list.

But I am searching for a dynamic solution with which I can insert values from a specific  table in my sql-database (USING SIMILAR SYNTAX TO THE EXAMPLE ABOVE - maybe using `.$fetch['role'].` ?).

Looking forward to receiving some suggestions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a table *roles* with the roles, and you are using PHP's MySqli methods, then your PHP code could look like this:

```
<?php
// ...
// ... assuming $mysqli is your connection object:
// ...
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT role FROM roles ORDER BY role") 
          or die($mysqli->error());

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $source[] = (object) array("value" => $row[0], "text" => $row[0]);
}
?>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.test').editable({    
            type: 'select',
            value: "keine",
            source: <?=json_encode($source)?>
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

So this code goes through the results from the database and builds an PHP array which has the structure you need in JavaScript.

Once this variable *$source* has been filled, it is written to the JavaScript in JSON format, which is (as PHP generates it, with all non-ASCII escaped) compatible with JavaScript.